# What's the easiest approach to automate startup tasks on Azure VMs?

Tags: azure

My current application scenario requires me to start several VM simultaneously with some startup tasks (the startup task on each VM triggers the same script but with different parameters). Previously in EC2 I can easily start a number of EC2 instances and then use Windows task scheduler easily to trigger the executable file, read the data in user-data of each instance and then everything is done.

I tried the same approach in Azure but found a number of issues:

1. Tried using task scheduler and start a task "at startup", but won't work since after syspreping the user information is lost and therefore I won't be able to start the same task.
2. Tried gpedit.msc and specify a startup script. Won't work. I don't know why.
3. Tried using task scheduler and start a task at a specific time point. Won't work. I've received an error message which says "the operator or administrator has refused the request".

So what's the simplest approach to automate a startup task in Azure VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you think about using the [Azure-powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_farnhill/archive/2014/01/22/managing-windows-azure-vms-through-powershell.aspx)?

1. You could use the `Start-AzureVM`-cmdlet to start your VMs.
2. You could use the following

code-snippet for starts:

```
$vmuri = Get-AzureWinRMUri -ServiceName $VMName

#region start hpc-azure-nodes
Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri $vmuri -Credential $credential {
    #start your tasks with the according parameters
} -ArgumentList
```

A considerably fancier way would be to create a head-vm in Azure and install a [HPC-cluster-manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919397.aspx). Utilizing the HPC-cluster-manager you can provision any number of Azure computing nodes within your limit, deploy your software and start/stop your software centrally from the cluster-manager.

Additionally the HPC-cluster-manager provides a number of helpful features:

- add/remove nodes
- connect via rdp to each node
- view logging information for your jobs
- and many, many more

There is also a [HPC-powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff950195.aspx) which provides a nice environment for automation. Admittedly this approach requires somewhat more effort but in the long run it almost certainly pays off.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is PowerShell Desired State Configuration (DSC).

This is a management platform introduced in PowerShell 4.0. You can use it to configure a VM or set of servers by providing a description of the desired state for each node in the system. Basically you can describe the state you want the server to be in when it boots up and if the configuration has drifted it will correct it.

A DSC script can:

- Manage registry keys
- Copy files and folders
- Run PowerShell scripts
- Deploy software
- Manage server roles
- Turn Windows features on/off

[Here is a quick tutorial at blog.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/08/07/introducing-the-azure-powershell-dsc-desired-state-configuration-extension.aspx) that will get you started.